# How to combine Day and Hour into one Date

Tags: excel, vba, date

I've got three textboxes (respectively for Date, Hour, Minute)

I need to paste the final Day/Month/Year Hour:Minute to a cell in Excel
with it formatted as a date

```
sDate = Format(myDate.Value & txtHour.Value & txtMinute.Value, "MM/DD/YYYY HH:MM")
.Cells(iRow, iCol + 1).Value = sDate
```

Help me out here? I'm scratching my head.

It's coming out like this.

04/26/20121437

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your date is already in the format of 04/26/27 you should be able to do something like

```
sDate = myDate.Value & " " & txtHour.Value & ":" & txtMinute.Value
.Cells(iRow, iCol + 1).Value = sDate
```

or

```
sDate = Format(myDate.Value, "MM/DD/YYYY") & " " & txtHour.Value & ":" & txtMinute.Value
.Cells(iRow, iCol + 1).Value = sDate
```

Comment: The only problem if the OP need a two digit number for hour and minute

Comment: + 1 :) You might want to change `sDate = myDate.Value & " " & txtHour.Value & ":" & txtMinute.Value` to `sDate = myDate.Value & " " & format(txtHour.Value."00") & ":" & format(txtMinute.Value,"00")` like Steve suggested.

Answer (score 0):

This is the cleanest way to do it. No string concatenation needed.

```
Dim d As Date
d = CDate(myDate.Value) + TimeSerial(txtHour.Value, txtMinute.Value, 0)
Range("A1") = d
Range("A1").NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm"

' If you *really* need the date as a string (which is rarely the case):
Dim s As String
s = Format(d, "mm/dd/yyyy hh:mm")
```

The only weak point is `CDate(myDate.Value)`. From VBA documentation:

> **CDate** recognizes date formats according to the locale setting of your system. The correct order of day, month, and year may not be determined if it is provided in a format other than one of the recognized date settings.

If the user decides to, for example, type the date in `dd/mm/yyyy` format instead of `mm/dd/yyyy` in `myDate`, then it will not work properly. Note that Zaider's solution has a similar weakness.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. TimeSerial is new to me. Thanks.